# Any clear winner for Data Science in Scala?

Tags: tools

I have found a number of libraries and tools for data science in Scala, I would like to know about which one has more adoption and which one is gaining adoption at a faster pace and to what extent this is the case. Basically, which one should I bet for (if any at this point).

Some of the tools I've found are (in no particular order):

- Scalding
- Breeze
- Spark
- Saddle
- H2O
- Spire
- Mahout
- Hadoop
- MongoDB

If I need to be more specific to make the question answerable: I'm not particularly interested in clusters and Big Data at this moment, but I'm interested in sizable data (up to 100 GB) for information integration and predictive analytics.

Comment: The question contains all kinds of types of technologies. It is like comparing apples to cars and asking which one has a better price-to-value ratio.

Comment: In Python there are clear winners like Pandas and Scikit. Which libraries would be the Pandas and the Scikit of Scala?

Comment: Now you are talking about at least only two types of libraries: numeric calculation (scikit) and table collections (pandas). Here is what the libraries you mentioned in your question are: Scalding (processing framework, functional API-layer for Hadoop), Breeze (linear algebra collections), Spark (processing framework), Saddle (table collections), H2O (a platform for ML), Spire (math collections), Mahout (ML library for Hadoop), Hadoop (batch processing framework), MongoDB (NoSQL document database). Scalding, Breeze, Sadle, Spire only are Scala-programming related. The others aren't.

Comment: I haven't used table libraries outside of R so far, but for Scala https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2015/08/21/data-frames-and-tables-in-scala/ might give you a head start.

Comment: When you write "scikit" - what do you mean? Do you mean "scipy" or all `scikit`s from http://scikits.appspot.com/scikits or do you mean the specifi `scikit` "scikit-learn"? Scipy is more an ecosystem of libraries than anything else.

Comment: Sorry, I mean scikit-learn. I think that one of the most basic and interesting workflows would be: load data (perhaps in a dataframe), explore and visualize it (matplotlib and similar), clean it and refine it (this should be operations on the data, perhaps dataframe), and train a model (classification and regression are the most usual). I think the only project trying to enable this may be Spark, but what I know is always less than what I do not know. Thank you.

Comment: Scala does not have much to offer in terms of visualisation. (If you find something good, please alert me!) Spark 2 made some big steps with fully integrated pipelines. So it might be a good choice for you (without the visualisation.) If you want interactivity, you might want to check out http://jupyter.org in combination with http://toree.apache.org. That's what I use when I teach Spark in professional (Data Science) courses.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure anybody have worked with *all* these tools, so I'm going to share my experience with some of them and let others share their experience with the others.

**MongoDB** addresses problems that involve heterogeneous and nested objects, while data mining mostly works with simple tabular data. MongoDB is neither fast with this type of data, nor provide any advanced tools for analysis (correct me if you know any). So I can think of a very few applications for Mongo in data mining.

**Hadoop** is a large ecosystem, containing dozens of different tools. I will assume that you mean core Hadoop features - HDFS and MapReduce. HDFS provides flexible way to store large amounts of data, while MapReduce gives basis for processing them. It has its clear advantages for processing multi-terabyte datasets, but it also has significant drawbacks. In particular, because of intensive disk IO during MapReduce tasks (that slows down computations a lot) it is terrible for interactive development, iterative algorithms and working with not-that-big datasets. For more details see my [earlier answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/863/1279).

Many algorithms in Hadoop require multiple MapReduce jobs with complicated data flow. This is where **Scalding** gets shiny. Scalding (and underlying Java's [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/)) provides much simpler API, but at the moment uses same MapReduce as its runtime and thus holds all the same issues.

**Spark** addresses exactly these issues. It drops Hadoop's MapReduce and offers completely new computational framework based on distributed in-memory collections and delayed evaluations. Its API is somewhat similar to Scalding's with all MR complexity removed, so it's really easy to get started with it. Spark is also the first in this list that comes with data mining library - [MLlib](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html).

But Spark doesn't reinvent things like basic linear algebra. For this purpose it uses **Breeze**. To my opinion, Breeze is far in quality from scientific packages like SciPy, Octave or Julia, but it is still good enough for most practical use cases.

---

**Mahout** relies on Hadoop's MapReduce and thus is terrible for iterative algorithms. **Spire** and **Saddle** look cute and probably have their niche, but seem to be much less well-known than Breeze. I couldn't find much information about **H2O**, so it doesn't look like a big player here (comments from people who used it are welcome).

---

Some quick summary. Spark seems to be the most simple, flexible and fast-growing project for large-scale data processing. It facilitates a number of new projects (e.g. Shark or Spark SQL) and penetrates into existing (including [Cascading](http://www.concurrentinc.com/2014/05/cascading-now-supports-tez-spark-and-storm-up-next/) and [Mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/users/sparkbindings/home.html)). Spark knows how to utilize HDFS API, and thus scales to terabytes of data easily. And for data mining downshifters who don't want to bother with a cluster setup there's always pure Breeze.